# Java. Count в JDBC PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Подскажите, как получить количество строк в БД через ResultSet и запрос count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("select count(*) from some_table");
int count = rs.getInt(1);
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое!
Помогло, правда перед получением значения нужно вызвать rs.next();